# EmberJS - how to restructure embedded models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember.js-view

**Note**: Using Ember Rails 0.18.2 and ember-source 1.12.1

I have inherited an Ember app that has a strange function. I am new to Ember so maybe this is normal, but I find it odd.

There are 3 models:

1. Parents
2. Games
3. Comments

When a Parent views a game the url looks like this:

```
/<parent slug>/games/<game_id>
```

(the slug is just a unique id for the parent).

At this url there is a template that has this code:

```
  {{#unless commentsOpen}}
  {{#link-to 'comments' class="Button easyButton"}}Chat with parents in your pod{{/link-to}}
  {{/unless}}

  {{outlet}}
```

Clicking the above button then changes the url to this:

```
/<parent slug>/games/<game_id>/comments
```

Then all the comments appear for that game.

I need to remove that button from the view and have Comments display automatically for each Game.

The API is Rails, and I can already change the API endpoint to return all the Comments at the same time a Game is requested (as an embedded array of objects).

But what do I replace {{outlet}} with? Because my understanding is that {{outlet}} is delegating to the Comments template due to this route:

```
App.CommentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    return this.store.find('comment', {
      game:   @modelFor('game').get('id')
      parent: @modelFor('parent').get('slug')
    }).then( (models) -> models.toArray() )
```

I believe I need to remove that route and make the Comments an embedded object inside the Game model. Do I then just replace outlet with something like:

```
{{#each comment in Game}}

<div class="commentItem">
  <div class="commentItem-author">{{comment.parent_name}}</div>
  <div class="commentItem-body">{{comment.body}}</div>
</div>

{{each}}
```

**EDIT**

This is the router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {
    path: '/'
  });
  return this.resource('parent', {
    path: '/:parent_id'
  }, function() {
    this.resource('games', {
      path: '/games'
    });
    return this.resource('game', {
      path: '/game/:game_id'
    }, function() {
      return this.resource('comments', {
        path: '/comments'
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Is your question about the restructuring of the model, or maybe more about how to load that model differently in regards to the routing structure and involved templates ?

Comment: More about how to change the template and routing structure to load the current models, since I don't believe the models need to change (although I could be wrong about that I suppose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedding the Comments inside Game is the answer. Then the view is like this:

```
{{#each comment in model.comments}}

<div class="commentItem">
    <div class="commentItem-author">{{comment.parent_name}}</div>
    <div class="commentItem-body">{{comment.body}}</div>
</div>

{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have your current app, and that presumably somewhere you have a list of games likes so:

```
{{#each games as |game|}}
  <li>
    {{#link-to 'game' game}}
       {{game.title}}
    {{/link-to}}
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

you should be able to route directly to the game with comments, by changing your link-to, like so:

```
{{#link-to 'games.game.comments' game}}
```

Here is a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/28d216680b61424583aca32e9048dd2a?openFiles=fixtures.all.js%2C&route=%2Fgames%2Fgame%2F1%2Fcomments) with a detailed solution

Comment: Thanks, tried that and get this error:
Assertion Failed: The attempt to link-to route 'games.game.comments' failed. The router did not find 'games.game.comments' in its possible routes

Comment: I tried adding that route as follows:
App.GameRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('games.game').comments;
  }
});

Comment: Ah yes, now that you've added your router, I see you are using this.resource. Using the link-to like I've suggested won't work while your routes are set up like that.